# Express Angular validation

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular with Express. My login form validation is not working. Here is the Jade code:

```
extends ../layout
script(type='text/javascript' src='../javascripts/admin/login.js')
block content
    .container
        .row
            .loginform(ng-controller='ExampleController')
                form.form-horizontal(name='loginForm' novalidate)
                    .control-group
                        label.control-label(for='inputEmail') Email
                        .controls
                            input(type='email' placeholder='Email' ng-model='login.email' name='uemail' required)
                            div(ng-show='loginForm.uemail.$dirty && loginForm.uemail.$invalid')
                                span(ng-show='loginForm.uemail.$error.required')
                                    span.help-inline Email is required
                                span(ng-show='loginForm.uemail.$error.email')
                                    span.help-inline Please fill a valid Email
                    .control-group
                        label.control-label(for='inputPassword') Password
                        .controls
                            input(type='password' placeholder='Password' ng-model='login.password')
                    .control-group
                        .controls
                            button.btn(type='submit') Sign in
```

My login.js is :

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.master={};
    }]);
```

I have checked and all my script files are getting loaded on the page. There is no error on console. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error. I just have to add "ng-app".

Answer (score 0):

it should work, can you try removing $dirty check on error display. also try initializing

```
     $scope.login = {}
```

on the controller.